# Subtração entre elementos em array Ruby

Tags: array, ruby, map

Olá,
Tenho um array de valores:

```
values = [3, 5, 12, 1, 2]
```

Gostaria que na primeira iteração todos os elementos do array fossem subtraídos pelo primeiro elemento (Ex, 5-3, 12-3, 1-3, 2-3)

```
# [2, 9, -2, -1]
```

Na segunda iteração (Ex, 12-5, 1-5, 2-5)

```
# [7, -4, -3]
```

Na terceira iteração (Ex, 1-12, 2-12)

```
# [-11, -10]
```

E assim sucessivamente. A subtração deve ocorrer a partir do elemento posterior. Tenho feito o seguinte:

```
values.map do |price|
 values.map do |value| 
  value - price 
 end 
end

# [[0, 2, 9, -2, -1], [-2, 0, 7, -4, -3], [-9, -7, 0, -11, -10], [2, 4, 11, 0, 1], [1, 3, 10, -1, 0]]
```

necessito de: `[2, 9, 7,-2, -1, 7, -4, -3, -11, -10, 1]`

Deixo meus agradecimentos por toda ajuda, dica e atenção para que eu consiga realizar a operação desejada.
Obrigado!

Comment: Pelo que entendi a cada iteração você pega o primeiro elemento do array, o subtrai de cada um dos outros elementos e o remove do array. Apesar de você ter dito "e assim sucessivamente" presumo que a iteração pare quando restar um único elemento no array. Você não explicou como tratar arrays bidimensionais e nem se o que colocou como "necessito" é o resultado esperado para a entrada existente após o "#".

Answer (score 0):

Fui meio na adivinhação (como comentaram, a explicação poderia ter sido mais clara) mas acredito que seja isso o que você quer:

```rb
values = [3, 5, 12, 1, 2]

(0...values.size).flat_map do |i|
  values[i+1..-1].map { |x| x - values[i] }
end

# => [2, 9, -2, -1, 7, -4, -3, -11, -10, 1]
```

---

Por partes:

`0...values.size` é um [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Range.html), representando o intervalo `[0, values.size)` (aberto na direita). Isso corresponde a um intervalo discreto sobre os índices do array. Sendo um `Range`, o valor também é um [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html), então temos acesso à função [flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map), que de forma simplificada equivale a um [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) seguido de um [flatten](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-flatten).

No `flat_map`, cada iteração retorna um array na forma que você descreveu: começando em um índice `i`, consideramos o subarray de `i+1` até o fim (identificado pelo índice `-1`) e subtraímos de cada elemento desse array o valor do elemento no índice `i`.

Note que cada iteração retorna um array, e o `flat_map` concatena esses arrays. Poderiamos fazer a mesma coisa com `map` e `flatten` assim:

```rb
values = [3, 5, 12, 1, 2]

iterations = (0...values.size).map do |i|
  values[i+1..-1].map { |x| x - values[i] }
end

# iterations => [[2, 9, -2, -1], [7, -4, -3], [-11, -10], [1], []]

iterations.flatten

# => [2, 9, -2, -1, 7, -4, -3, -11, -10, 1]
```